# Fade Out, Fade In Transaction Effect - Flash Action Script 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fadein, fadeout, effect

Basically I have a pre loader that shows progress of how much the showcase has loaded. When this has finished loading it moves onto the first/home frame. I want do a fade in, fade out effect during this between these two frames.

As these two frames are right next to each other I am presuming that action script is the only possible way of achieving this.

How would I go about doing this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're using motion tweens in the frame, I honestly recommend using [greensock](http://www.greensock.com/)

It's got a great tweening engine and examples, that will help you tween exactly how you want.

Because this is a preloader, you might not be able to put them all into one frame so your code should be in your Document class (master .as file)

Comment: Thanks, will look into this. How hard would it be to do the effects described in the question?

Comment: Not that hard. Here's some sample code : import com.greensock.*;
TweenLite.to(mc, 1, {alpha:0}); You can now fade out your movieclip in 1 second!